# Angular2 changes to (click) functions not working

Tags: typescript, angular

I've been messing around with Angular2 and I have no idea why my changes to these functions do nothing. So say my code first looks like this:

```
//home.component.html
<div class="ui container">

<sm-button class="positive" (click)="remove()">Button</sm-button>

</div>

//home.component.ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "home",
    templateUrl: `client/components/home/home.component.html`
})
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor() {}
    remove() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
}
```

But then I change it to this:

```
//home.component.html
<div class="ui container">

<sm-button class="positive" (click)="load()">Button</sm-button>

</div>

//home.component.ts
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "home",
    templateUrl: `client/components/home/home.component.html`
})
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor() {}
    load() {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
}
```

Now the load function cannot be found when clicking the button. What is going on here?

EDIT: changed code to include full files

Comment: have you add template in `@Component`

Comment: did you forget to compile?  It would help if you posted both files, before and after.

Comment: Yes. The template loads the button and pressing it works when the click function is remove. It's like the changes I make in home.component.ts aren't actually doing anything. Why would that be happening? I have lite-server running so shouldn't it auto compile on changes or do I still need to compile manually?

Comment: it depends on if you are running the server concurrently with "tsc -w"  If you are just running lite-server, it will only watch for file changes and then refresh, but it won't compile for you.  Try running tsc and see if it works then.

Comment: I am running with "tsc -w"

Comment: Just change now load with your name awillis() and try

Answer (score 0):

Seems like tsc-w doesnt work properly.
Look into server console, was command run or not.
Also, try to clear console cache.
Look at your javascript generates sources and check, whether it was updated or not